# Route params constraints keeping format from being detected properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Rails 3.1.3**.

```
# routes.rb
get "posts/:id" => "posts#show", :constraints => { :id => /\d.+/ }
```

In the rails console

```
> Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("posts/101-haha.js")
=> {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :id=>"101-haha.js"}
```

My `rake routes` gives

```
GET      /posts/:id(.:format)
```

So since `.:format` appears to be implicit, why isn't it detecting the format correctly? Is it cause my constraint is too *greedy*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/\d.+/` is eating up the dot "." in the ".js".
Try to escape it:

```
get "posts/:id" => "posts#show", :constraints => { :id => /\d([^\.].)+/ }
```

http://rubular.com/r/ecqCnnYBpK

Comment: So it is what I have feared. Thanks. Wouldn't the constraint `\d[^\.]+` also work?

Comment: Maybe engineer the regex to allow dots but skip the last one, not sure if possible, if not make a class that does it computationally and give that as constraint.